# Why does this xslt transformation replace all occurences?

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0

Using http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<my:project xmlns:my="http://myns">
<my:properties>
 <my:property>
  <my:name>customerId</my:name>
  <my:value>1</my:value>
 </my:property>
 <my:property>
  <my:name>userId</my:name>
  <my:value>20</my:value>
 </my:property>
</my:properties>
</my:project>
```

I now want to look for the name `customerId` and want to replace the `value`.

It almost works, but it replaces ALL values in the document. What am I doing wrong to just replace the value where the name mached?

.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="http://myns" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net"> 

 <xsl:param name="name" select="'customerId'"/>
 <xsl:param name="value" select="'0'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/my:properties/my:property/my:value/text()" > 
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="/*/my:properties/my:property/my:name = $name">
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse(.)" /></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for `/*/my:properties/my:property/my:name = $name` always succeed because it uses an absolute path, and so the result is independent of the surrounding template context. A test with a relative xpath should work.

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="http://myns" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net"> 

    <xsl:param name="name" select="'customerId'"/>
    <xsl:param name="value" select="'0'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/my:properties/my:property/my:value/text()" > 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../../my:name = $name">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>otherwise</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<my:project xmlns:my="http://myns">
    <my:properties>
        <my:property>
            <my:name>customerId</my:name>
            <my:value>1</my:value>
        </my:property>
        <my:property>
            <my:name>userId</my:name>
            <my:value>20</my:value>
        </my:property>
    </my:properties>
</my:project>
```

Result of `saxonb-xslt -s:test.xml -xsl:test.xsl`

```
<my:project xmlns:my="http://myns">
    <my:properties>
        <my:property>
            <my:name>customerId</my:name>
            <my:value>0</my:value>
        </my:property>
        <my:property>
            <my:name>userId</my:name>
            <my:value>otherwise</my:value>
        </my:property>
    </my:properties>
</my:project>
```

Comment: @membersound: I added the complete example I tested, what error did you get?

Comment: Ok you're right, it works as expected. Thank you! The problem seemed to be the `saxon:parse(.)` statement. Just using `.` everything works.